# How to modify custom ButtonStyle animations

Tags: ios, button, swiftui

You can modify the highlight/press state of `Button`s with SwiftUI by implementing your own `ButtonStyle` which modifies the `label` based on the `isPressed` state.

In iOS 13, this was animated both on touch down and touch up. In iOS 14 beta, it does not animate on press down, only up. I want to enable animation on touch down. How can this be done?

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)
    }
}

struct CustomButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.pink)
        }
        .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

[image: Recording of difference between iOS 14 and 13]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply define an explicit animation in your button style `make body`.
for example, you can add `.animation(.easeOut)` below `.scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)`